# Android Studio consumindo 100% de disco

Tags: android-studio

Meu Android Studio fica consumindo 100% do disco durante todo o tempo, mesmo quando não tem nenhuma tarefa executando no backgroud, esse uso de disco deixa todo o sistema muito lento.
Olhando no Gerenciador de Tarefas não é só o Android Studio que fica usando o disco, as vezes é o System, as vezes é o Java, mas sempre quando ele está aberto, seu eu fecho o Android Studio o uso de disco volta ao normal.

Alguém mais tem esse problema? É normal do Android Studio? Tem como resolver?

A versão do Android Studio é 2.3 (o problema ocorria mesmo nas versões anteriores).
Windows 10 64 bits.
Core i5-5200U, 4GB de ram.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Pelo que descobri o Android Studio estava com pouca memória RAM, acho que por isso ele usava muito a paginação de disco, mudei as configurações para aumentar a memória no menu **Help > Edit Custom VM Options...**. 
Deixei assim:

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
-Xms1560m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=450m
```

No meu caso isso resolveu, o uso de disco está normal agora.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar "Power Save" opção no menu Arquivo.

ou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentei os dois, mas não resolveu.